# J2ME Mobile Application

Tags: database, java-me, sms

I have a scenario. When a person sends a message to a specific mobile which is connected to the system, the message is extracted from the mobile connected to the system and this is used for a SELECT statement to get some values from the database. Then this answer is sent back to the person who sent the previous message. 
I am not sure if I can do this. I need some tips on how this can be achieved ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure where you want to use SMS or why in all that. Could you add more information? I would seem strange to me to send an SQL query via SMS...

Comment: for example if i am going to send my id,it will send a message informing the new mails tat this id received.. i use the value of the id sent for a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you phone is meant to act as an SMS Gateway. You might need [SMSlib](http://www.smslib.org), where you can connect the phone to your system and listen for messages and process the messages when they arrive and send back a response to the same number from which the message was received